# Why does the required field validator not work if I click twice?

Tags: html, asp.net, validation

I have a form on an aspx page that asks for an email address. I want email address to be a required field so I am using a `RequiredFieldValidator` to force the user to enter email address.

The validator works on the first click, i.e. the code associated with the submit click won't execute, however it will submit the form if you click a second time even though there is still no email in the email field.

Am I using this incorrectly? Should I just use javascript instead of this class?

```
            <tr>
                <th class="style1"><strong>Email: </strong></th>
                <th class="style2"><asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" class="textboxes"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="email"
                    ErrorMessage="Email is a required field."
                    ForeColor="Red"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You probably use UpdatePanel, and you are not update again the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice, always use Page.Isvalid in server side to prevent such kind of scripts errors.

```
if (Page.IsValid)
                {
                    //do stuffs
                }
```